# How to schedule and export Dashboard from Einstein Analytic

Tags: einstein-analytics

Good day, All

Here I have question on the Einstein Dashboard usage, with the version we have, there is no schedule or auto trigger function on it, so user would get the Dashboard by access URL only. Should be this be default or limitation?

Otherwise, when we try to download the Dashboard, it provide the .PNG file only, should this designed by Einstein default? Should there any other file format active ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Einstein Analytics dashboards is build up of multiple widgets usually and these widget might belong to many different datasets as per requirement.
Hence it is not possible to download dashboard as data (csv or any other format). 
You can however share the dashboards via chatter where the image file would be send along with link to the dashboard (only if user has analytics licence and access to dashboard ).

You can download individual widget data as they are basically lenses. When you go to sharing options of lenses, you will see download option there. Please remember that the data downloaded will be based on the query limit which is defined in your lense, you can change to maximum of 10000.

If you do not see the download option in lense, visit following link to make configuration changes to enable that.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_setup_download_enable.htm&type=5

Thanks